# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined when image upload is empty in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried testing my ionic image upload app in browser but since I can not upload image due to cordova_not_available been displayed on the screen, every time I click ed on the upload button this error pop up **Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**

**

NewpostPage.html:51 ERROR ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined    at new Transfer (VM1294 vendor.js:149642)    at NewpostPage.webpackJsonp.162.NewpostPage.uploadPhoto (VM1295 main.js:601)    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VM1527 NewpostPage.ngfactory.js:180)    at handleEvent (VM1294 vendor.js:13963)    at callWithDebugContext (VM1294 vendor.js:15472)    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (VM1294 vendor.js:15059)    at dispatchEvent (VM1294 vendor.js:10378)    at VM1294 vendor.js:11003    at HTMLButtonElement. (VM1294 vendor.js:39326)    at t.invokeTask (VM1427 polyfills.js:3)

**

in my **upload.ts** i have this

```
 uploadPhoto() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait..."
    });
    loader.present();

    //let filename = this.imagePath.split('/').pop();
    console.log('this.imagePath: ', this.imagePath)
    let filename = this.imagePath;
    let options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      params: {'location': this.location, 'title': this.postTitle, 'description': this.desc }
    };


    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();

    fileTransfer.upload(this.imageNewPath, AppSettings.API_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT,
      options).then((entry) => {
        this.imagePath = '';
        this.imageChosen = 0;
        loader.dismiss();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(IncidentsPage);
      }, (err) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  }

  chooseImage() {

    let actionSheet = this.actionSheet.create({
      title: 'Choose Picture Source',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Gallery',
          icon: 'albums',
          handler: () => {
            this.actionHandler(1);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Camera',
          icon: 'camera',
          handler: () => {
            this.actionHandler(2);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    actionSheet.present();
  }


  //}

  actionHandler(selection: any) {
    var options: any;

    if (selection == 1) {
      options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 500,
        targetHeight: 500,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      };
    } else {
      options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 500,
        targetHeight: 500,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      };
    }

    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imgUrl) => {

      var sourceDirectory = imgUrl.substring(0, imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      var sourceFileName = imgUrl.substring(imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imgUrl.length);
      sourceFileName = sourceFileName.split('?').shift();
      File.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName, cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, sourceFileName).then((result: any) => {
        this.imagePath = imgUrl;
        this.imageChosen = 1;
        this.imageNewPath = result.nativeURL;

      }, (err) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      })

    }, (err) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(err))
    });

  }
```

Please help out.

Comment: For whatever reason it seems like this.imagePath is undefined. Before you try to split() do console.log('this.imagePath: ', this.imagePath) and check if the variable is what you expect it to be. If not go back and work out why.

Comment: @Shannon, yes, it's undefined. Could you please help me out. I am new to ionic. Thanks.

Comment: Without getting intimate with your code i cannot know how to solve the problem. You need to look at this.imagePath from the start of its life cycle and see why it is undefined. Meaning it has no value and you obviously set a value for it at some point, where did it go wrong?

Comment: @Shannon, please check. I have updated my code. Thanks.

Comment: I can see you set this.imagePath inside getPicture().then() is it undefined there?

Comment: Is there supposed to be something in this.imagePath or are you trying to prevent the code running when the button is clicked and nothing is there?

Comment: @Shannon, wants it to return the image after it's been uploaded. But if no image uploaded, I don't want it to give undefined, instead it should just insert other values without the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178017/discussion-between-shannon-and-tonye-boro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i see what you are asking now.

You need to check for undefined and "" before running the code inside uploadPhoto().

```
uploadPhoto() {

if(this.imagePath !== undefined || this.imagePath !== '') {
let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait..."
    });
    loader.present();

    //let filename = this.imagePath.split('/').pop();
    console.log('this.imagePath: ', this.imagePath)
    let filename = this.imagePath;
    let options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      params: {'location': this.location, 'title': this.postTitle, 'description': this.desc }
    };


    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();

    fileTransfer.upload(this.imageNewPath, AppSettings.API_UPLOAD_ENDPOINT,
      options).then((entry) => {
        this.imagePath = '';
        this.imageChosen = 0;
        loader.dismiss();
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(IncidentsPage);
      }, (err) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  }
} else {
    //do something else

}
```